# Mobile site for existing app- New application or conditional rendering in existing app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, sencha-touch

I am going to create a mobile site(using Sencha touch) for an existing website. The functionalities are coded already using Ruby on Rails. If I go with adding mobile site to existing one it will make me to add conditional rendering based on the request headers or else go with creating a separate app on m.mydomain.com. I am a bit confused. Please guide me to make a decision.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend creating conditional rendering inside the existing application, primarily because you will have access to the models and utility classes within that application.

If that's a significant problem for you, you could separate out the two codebases and have the mobile site be an engine of the application, so you would still have access to the main application's classes.

Comment: Thanks ryan... could you suggest a good tutorial for sencha touch on rails?

Comment: No sorry, I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with m.mydomain.com and redirect the user to this automatically based on their device. T

he good thing about this is that you can have a link at the bottom of the page that is "View full website" in case the mobile site isn't what the user wants.

This also makes it easy to have separate views for the mobile site, keeping them cleaner.

I recently made a sample app that you can view on github that does something very similar. The only difference is that I am not detecting the device, I have the user visit the appropriate URL. I also used jquery mobile, but the concepts are very similar. https://github.com/jfriedlaender/mobile_blog